# What is imported from an Access database for empty boxes?

Tags: python, pandas, ms-access, types, pyodbc

I got a pandas DataFrame of a table I have imported from an Access database. Some of the values in that Access table are empty. As I was playing with the data frame, I stumbled into this situation: The type of the data in a specific box (row, column) does not match a the corresponding boolean statement.

```
type(df.loc['3000', 'email'])
>>> NoneType
type(df.loc['3000', 'email']) == None
>>> False
```

Tried several ways but it seems like the data is printed out as None but isn't actually None.
Any idea why? What is actually imported for empty boxes? What will be a True equality statement? Thank you.

Comment: `df.loc['3000', 'email'] == None`

Comment: Try `df.dropna()` and count up what's left.

Comment: type(df.loc['3000', 'email']) == type(None)

Comment: @NickODell - Testing `thing == None` is not recommended practice. `thing is None` is preferred.

Comment: @Neo - Testing `type(x) == type(y)` is also discouraged (PEP8 E721). The preferred construct for that test would be `isinstance(thing, types.NoneType)`, but `thing is None` is better.

Comment: @NickODell - That statement returnd that all **aren't** None.

Comment: Thanks all. It was more a question about the type of data that is imported from an Access database for empty boxes. Printing the pandas data frame resulted whith a None value. But it seemed like it isn't actually None.